# What is the correct, efficient way for threads to communicate under Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

What is the correct, efficient, way for threads (within a service) to communicate under Android?

I have looked at Intents (serialization overhead), HandlerThreads and Loopers (bundling overheads).

A receiving thread should have have (synchronized) queue(s) to which objects (of types known at compile time) can be added.

I have previously written such functionality for JavaME, but I was under the impression that Android would have a "standard" efficient way of communicating between threads, using compile-time-known types.

Am I missing something fundamental?  (I do not have much recent Java experience beyond JavaME/1.3.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native way to send messages to a thread is `Handler`'s. If that doesn't meet your requirements (which are?), you can implement a thread messaging system yourself using Java primitives and/or  `java.util.concurrent` classes.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [MessageQueues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html) ?

Comment: Messages seem to need bundles, etc.  If they were spelled Message<MyClass> then they might have been the right solution.

Comment: Ok I see. In that case I don't think there is an Android way for that.